# How to resize a vector c++

Tags: c++, vector, resize

```
int main()
{
    vector<list<string> > tail;
    int x;
    cin >> x;

    if (x == 1) {
        vector<list<string> > tail(1);
    }
}
```

Is it possible to resize a `vector<list<...> >`..?

Comment: `tail.resize(10,list<string>());` maybe? Why not?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code sample has a serious flaw, the `tail` variable is shadowed in the local scope and might not work like you are expecting:

```
int main()
{
    vector<list<string> > tail;
    int x;
    cin >> x;

    if (x == 1) {
        vector<list<string> > tail(1); // A new tail variable local to the block
                                       // scope, this does effectively nothing
    }
}
```

You probably want to have something like this

```
int main()
{
    vector<list<string> > tail;
    int x;
    cin >> x;

    if (x == 1) {
        tail.resize(1,list<string>());
    }
}
```